# How do I check the video bitrate of an Ogg Theora (ogv) video file?

Tags: video, bitrate, theora

I've been sent an .ogv file by a video company that's 4 times the file size of the equivalent MP4 file. I suspect they've encoded it at way too high a bitrate, but I'd like to check for sure.

I'm on Windows 7 (64bit) but have other OSes (e.g. Mac OS 10.8.5) available too.

I've tried using the 'media information' window in VLC media player - but for some reason that only shows the bitrate of the audio stream, not the video stream!

I've also tried installing the [XIPH Directshow filters](http://www.xiph.org/dshow/) in the hope that this might make Win7 show the encoding detail in Windows Explorer or via Media Player, like it does for MP4 files - but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [ffmpeg for windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Use it like this

```
ffmpeg.exe -i file.ogg
```

Output will be like this

```
ffmpeg version N-56980-g1ab9f32 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  8 2013 18:02:10 with gcc 4.8.1 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 46.101 / 52. 46.101
  libavcodec     55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavformat    55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavdevice    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavfilter     3. 88.101 /  3. 88.101
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[ogg @ 023eb3c0] Broken file, keyframe not correctly marked.
Input #0, ogg, from 'file.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:30.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 501 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: theora, yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps,
 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : VLC media player
At least one output file must be specified
```

The bitrate is at the line

> Duration: 00:00:30.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 501 kb/s